# Double Array display in jade

Tags: arrays, node.js, pug

I have this array setup:

```
var threads = ["one", "two", "three"]
var data = [
     [11,21,31],
     [12,22,32],
     [13,23,33],
  ]
```

and I want it in html like this:

```
one  two  three
11   21   31
12   22   32
12   23   33
```

Right now I pass the array with nodejs (Express) to my layout.jade

```
   table
    thead
      each val in {threads}
        +tablethread(val)
    tbody
      -for (var i = 0; i < {data}.length; i++) {
        tr
        -for (var o = 0; o < {data[i]}.length; o++) {
            +tableval(data[i][o])
```

Can someone help me to get the arrays rendered right?
(the mixins are also defined on the top of layout.jade)

```
  mixin tableval(val)
     td= val
  mixin tablethread(name)
     th= name
```

I get this error right now: `SyntaxError: Unexpected token (146:22)`

Comment: What output do you get?

Comment: SyntaxError: Unexpected token (146:22)

Comment: Have you tried using variables without braces e.g. `each val in threads` instead of `each val in {threads}` ?

Comment: @MohitBhardwaj Yes I did. The number "Unexpected token (146:22)" changed to (219:19). I think the first number is the line but I don't have more than 50 lines in my file.

Comment: Please do that with every instance of `{//your-variable}` in your file

Comment: @MohitBhardwaj I have tried with ervery instance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this in jade:

```
- var threads = ["one", "two", "three"]
- var data = [ [11,21,31], [12,22,32], [13,23,33], ]

table
  tr
    for thread in threads
      th=thread
  for values in data
    tr
      for i in values
        td=i
```

This will compile into the following HTML:

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <th>one</th>
    <th>two</th>
    <th>three</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>11</td>
    <td>21</td>
    <td>31</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>12</td>
    <td>22</td>
    <td>32</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>13</td>
    <td>23</td>
    <td>33</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

I've got a working example of this on codepen [here](http://codepen.io/AdamCCFC/pen/dXmGWj).

Comment: That will work but  I can't pass variables to the jade file.

Comment: @Colin This will work even if you pass variables in the context object as is done normally.